# How can I use other software DLLs in my C# application?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I use third-party software DLLs in my C# Windows application?

Comment: Is this about using functions from a dll, or executing a binary?  Those are two completely different questions.

Comment: You're not doing this in C# *and* Java. Which one is it? Don't just toss every tag you can think of onto your question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the dll contains. If it's a .NET assembly you can add a reference to it and compile your project against that assembly.

If it's a COM component you will have to [expose the component to .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3.aspx) by creating a Runtime Callable Wrapper. Visual studio does this automatically for you if you add a reference to a COM component.

If it's a dll with a C style API you have to use [Platform Invocation (PInvoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in order to call functions inside it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a dll u cannot start using process.start
if it is a unmanaged dll u have to use DllImport otherwise reference it to ur project and use their methods

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to add a reference to the DLL in your project and add a using statement, which declares the namespace of the classes you wish to use...

EDIT:
Adding references to third party DLLs using Visual Studio 2008:

- in VS2008 open the project folder
- right click on the `References` Folder
- click `add Reference`
- select the `Browse` tab
- go to the DLL you wish to reference
- select it and click ok

Comment: could you please tell me that how can i add reference in my application i am implementing this in c#.net.